# How to prevent h2o cluster shutdown without notice using R

Tags: r, h2o

I am a h2o R version user and I have a question regarding the h2o local cluster. I setup the cluster by execute the command in r,

`h2o.init()`

However, the cluster will be turned off automatically when I do not use it for a few hours. For example, I run my model during the night, but when I come back to my office in the morning to check on my model. It says,

`Error in h2o.getConnection() : No active connection to an H2O cluster. Did you runh2o.init()?`

Is there a way to fix or work around it ?

Comment: H2O does not shut itself down automatically.  There must be something else happening on your machine that's causing the cluster to be killed.  Did you run `h2o.init()` to try to re-connect?  Have you double-checked that the underlying H2O Java process is not running? Did you `ssh` into the cluster, start H2O and then logged out? (that will kill any process unless you use `screen` or `nohup` and is unrelated to H2O)

Comment: I can reconnect back to the cluster. However, the model I trained is no longer in the cluster even tough I reconnect it back. I guess it's now in the r environment. I can check the result of the model by typing the model name in r console. However, I am not able to use any h2o built-in function to utilize the model such as 'h2o.performance' or 'h2o.predict', etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the H2O cluster is still running, then your models are all still there (assuming they finished training successfully).  There are a number of ways that you can check if the H2O Java cluster is still running.  In R, you can check the output of these functions:

```
h2o.clusterStatus()
h2o.clusterInfo()
```

At the command line (look for a Java process):

```
ps aux | grep java
```

If you started H2O from R, then you should see a line that looks something like this:

```
yourusername     26215   0.0  2.7  8353760 454128   ??  S     9:41PM  21:25.33 /usr/bin/java -ea -cp /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/h2o/java/h2o.jar water.H2OApp -name H2O_started_from_R_me_iqv833 -ip localhost -port 54321 -ice_root /var/folders/2j/jg4sl53d5q53tc2_nzm9fz5h0000gn/T//Rtmp6XG99X
```

H2O models do not live in the R environment, they live in the H2O cluster (a Java process).  It sounds like what's happening is that the R object representing your model (which is actually just a pointer to the model in the H2O cluster) is having issues finding the model since your cluster disconnected.  I don't know exactly what's going on because you haven't posted the errors you're receiving when you try to use `h2o.predict()` or `h2o.performance()`.

To get the model back, you can use the `h2o.getModel()` function.  You will need to know the ID of your model.  If your model object (that's not working properly) is still accessible, then you can see the model ID easily that way: `model@model_id`  You can also head over to H2O Flow in the browser (by typing: http://127.0.0.1:54321 if you started H2O with the defaults) and view all the models by ID that way.

Once you know the model ID, then refresh the model by doing:

```
model <- h2o.getModel("model_id")
```

This should re-establish the connection to your model and the `h2o.predict()` and `h2o.performance()` functions should work again.

Comment: When the cluster is running, I have no problem using the model. However, the problem is, when I setup the h2o cluster from R and run the model during the night, the cluster is disconnected when I check the cluster status in the morning. I am sure the training process is finished because I can see the summary result of the model when I type the model name in R console. However, I just can not use it for prediction because the h2o cluster is disconnected. Do the cluster have any default setting like, if we do not use it for a period of time, then it will shut down itself automatically ?

Comment: No, H2O will never shut itself down.  Only the user can do that, or possibly some other process on the machine kills the Java process (unrelated to H2O).  If you're running this on a remote machine, then you need to use `screen` or `nohup` otherwise all processes will be killed when you lose the ssh connection to the machine.

Comment: Have you double-checked that the H2O Java process is no longer running? I am still confused as to whether the cluster is simply disconnected from you R session or if the cluster Java job is no longer running. You said "I can reconnect back to the cluster."  Do you mean you can create a new cluster or you can reconnect to former cluster that contains your models? If it's not running, then unless you saved the models in your script using `h2o.saveModel()`, your models are gone (they exist only in memory until you save them).

Comment: I mean I can create a new cluster by typing ```h2o.init()```, not reconnecting to the previous cluster. How can I check the h2o java process and see if it's running ? Thank you

Comment: And yes, I am using a remote machine. I need to ssh to the remote machine and do a port forwarding so that I can use rstudio server from my own laptop.

Comment: Well, if you are connecting to a remote machine, then you really need to investigate using `screen` or `nohup`, otherwise when you local console loses the connection, your remote jobs will die.  Is the R process still running when you log in in the morning, or is that killed too?  I updated the answer with info on how to check if the H2O Java cluster is running.

Comment: I have used the `h2o.clusterInfo()` function in R and it's no longer running. All informations are still stored in the RStudio Server environment when I reconnected. I guess that's because the system saved the current version to local, so when I connect again, it just loads all previous saved information back to the new R environment. That explains why I can still see my h2o model in R environment but I can no longer use it for prediction.